# Transit visa with Costa Rica passport - Zurich

Tags: uk, transit-visas, switzerland, costa-rican-citizens

I'm changing planes from Costa Rica to the UK at Zurich - do I need a transit visa. I have a Costa Rican passport.

Answer (score 1):

No. Costa Rica is on the list of visa-exempt countries for entry into the Schengen Area https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/apply_for_a_visa_en